# How to extract characters from a filename

Tags: bash

I have a list which contains file names. How can I get create a new list which contains only the first 4 characters of every line?

Comment: What format is the list in?

Comment: a simple text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` to only show the first (up to) 4 characters of each line:

```
grep -Eo '^.{,4}' /PATH/TO/FILE
```

`-E` enables extended regular expressions, which is needed for the curly braces quantifier here.
`-o` makes `grep` output only the matched part, not the whole line on which it was found

The pattern `^.{,4}` matches at the beginning of a line (`^`) a sequence consisting of any character (`.`) and being up to 4 characters long (`{,4}`).

To save the output as a file, simply use redirection:

```
grep -Eo '^.{,4}' /PATH/TO/FILE > /PATH/TO/OUTPUT-FILE
```

---

Follow-up:

For a generic pattern to match a specific range (from x-th character to y-th character), consider this example, which displays the 10th through 18th character of each line:

```
$ echo 123456789abcdefghij | grep -Po '(?<=^.{9}).{8}'
abcdefgh
```

This is achieved by skipping the 9 first characters without matching them using a so-called lookbehind (`(?<=...)`). This feature is not included in the extended regular expressions understood by `grep`, therefore we need `-P` instead to enable PCRE.

After exactly 9 characters have been skipped, it matches the next exactly 8 characters. If the line is shorter than that, it will not match. To match up to 8 characters again, as in the first part of this answer, write `{,8}` instead of `{8}`.

Comment: and if I want to grep from the character 10 up to 18 ? What is the rule?

Comment: See my edit. You need to skip the first 9 characters using a lookbehind first and then match however many characters you want to show.